# Writing using Regular Expressions in Google Cloud query

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform

I currently have a regular expression: `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'\"createdAt\"\:(.*?)\}')`
Which finds "`createAt":`" and outputs anything past that  text and up until the next "`}`".

Example output: `{"_seconds":1620327345,"_nanoseconds":155071000`

This works **BUT** I need the last `}` to be included in the output.

Preferred Output: `{"_seconds":1620327345,"_nanoseconds":155071000}`

How will I need to change my regular expression so that the `}` is included in the output?

Comment: Note I am writing my query in SQL and there is nothing else I can end the regex with other than }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `}` into the capturing group:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'"createdAt":(.*?})')
```

Besides, you can make it a bit more efficient with a negated character class:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'"createdAt":([^}]*})')
```

With `[^}]*`, you match any zero or more chars other than `}` as many times as possible.

Also, if you chose single quotation marks as a string literal delimiter char, you need not escape double quotation marks (they are not special regex metacharacters.) Note `}` is not a special character if there is no paired `{` with a number (or `{<number>,<number>`) in front of it.